# NRefactory 5 add empty line

Tags: c#, nrefactory

I'm using NRefactory 5 to generate C# code. In certain cases, I need to insert in my output code an empty line to obtain a more readable code.
I can't find any command to do this in NRefactory, so at the moment the only one solution that I found is to add a '\n' in the output string obtained from the syntaxTree.getText() function.
Exists a better solution?

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

You can insert a newline node in the AST. For example, to insert a newline in front of `node`:

```
node.Parent.InsertChildBefore(node, new UnixNewLine(), Roles.NewLine);
```

The output visitor ignores the type of newline you use; it'll just end up calling `textWriter.WriteLine();`.